# how to run MySQL query in Linux that allow lower case table name and my query which contains table name in camel case?

Tags: mysql, linux

In Linux server I am Configure Apache and PhpMyadmin.

In the database my table's name is **`mst_vehicle`**

when I fire a query like **`select * from mst_vehicle`** it will give right result, **but**

When I fire a query like **`select * from Mst_Vehicle`** It will give an error.

Please help me how to resolve this problem.

I import the database from windows to linux phpmyadmin and my windows database is already with lower case table name.

Comment: This seems correct. If your table is named `mst_vehicle`, your query should be `select * from mst_vehicle`, not `Mst_Vehicle`. I'd suggest changing either your code or table names so they match; relying on the case insensitivity is not what I would consider a good practice.

Comment: Yes, I am rename my all table name and column name in my all queries and its work perfactly.

Answer (score 3):

**Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.**

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the
>   underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names. This means database and table names are not
>   case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of
>   Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses
>   a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive.

Have a look at [**Identifier Case Sensitivity.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Thanks for replay. but My operating system is linux redhat and i am configured apache server and mysql (phpmyadmin) in linux. what change will allow me to fire this type of query?

Comment: You need to pass table name in actual case in which it is.

Comment: I was using Select * From Mst_Vehicle; Type Query in my project all file when this type of query fire from that files it will not work. what can i do? Changes doing all files is very time consuming and i haven't that much time..is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Yes you can rename table according to your case Example : `RENAME TABLE temp_table TO Temp_Table`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct case-sensitive table name from case-ignorant name by doing this:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where lower(table_name)="mst_vehicle" and table_schema="YourDatabaseName"
```

It will however add a performance penalty.